# gvim not recognizing NERDTree as an editor command

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm using gvim and following the windows setup steps of vundle:
https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows

After the steps, I found the nerdtree plugin is successfully installed, I can find it under ~/vimfiles/bundle.

And I customize the _vimrc file like below:

```
set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim/
let path='~/vimfiles/bundle'
call vundle#begin(path)

Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
```

So I restarted gvim, and type :NERDTree, the editor is raising the error:E492 Not and editor command: NERDTree

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have `call vundle#end()` somewhere?

Comment: Oh, that's the problem! So stupid to miss vundle#end() call at the end. Thanks dude, the problem is gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `call vundle#end()` after all your plugin declarations for vundle to actually modify your runtime path.